# JBOSS EAP 6 - Siteminder integration components

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, siteminder

I need to set up JBOSS EAP6 WebApp to integrate with Siteminder with IDP initiated SAML2 artifact binding.The current integration is using Form based header authentication. Siteminder is onPrem and JBOSS/App is in AWS. I have little visibility to the siteminder set up or it's requirement to integrate to JBOSS. I have a clarity on setting up the ServiceProvider in JBOSS for SSO and Single Log out with post binding.
My question are:
1. To integrate with an OnPrem Siteminder IDM, what components other than JBOSS and it's configurations are to be present in the server hosting JBOSS?
Something like a siteminder agent to be run in the server?
From a purely JBOSS perspective ,where does the JBOSS set up boundary starts?
I went through the net and could not find a conclusive list of components required to meet this integration.
2. Artifact binding is not supported by JBOSS EAP 6 per [doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/version-6.4/how-to-setup-sso-with-saml-v2/), so I must ask the IDM team to support SSO with post binding, correct?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is picketlink that needs to be configured.Github has [examples][1]

[1]: https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts . 
There is no need of siteminder agent if SP set up alone in the scope.
Also IDM team has to be requested to stick to POST Binding.

This covers the questions I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implemented your own JAAS security module. There is information on JBoss and CA websites on how to do this. This module will provide the authenication (user) and authorization (roles) to the applications deployed on JBoss. When developing I suggest setting the log level of org.jboss.security to trace.

Comment: This is too generic an answer.I am aware that SAML2logon module has to be configured and it's handler should be written.Unfortunately it does not answer the specific questions I asked.